# can I change value of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?

Tags: php

I am setting up a testing environment for a client project for an application that was already programmed by someone else. I have created a subdirectory called `iftc` in the hosting account that we normally use for such purposes.

Now, all include files are not being found as they are being referenced through

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Includes/Connect.php');
```

And so on.

Short of setting up a *whole new* hosting account just for testing purposes for this particular client, can I change the value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` somehow to include a subfolder `iftc` that the files are in?

Comment: If you can create a subdomain in your hosting account, that should get its own document root.

Comment: I think that's what I going to do, with eventually re-writing the code according to "my preferred solution" below

Comment: I started using \_\_dir__ as a way to prepend my paths which at-least brings some consistency to relative paths-- as long as everything uses \_\_dir__

Comment: Create a new VirtualHost for the testing environment. Probably means you may need to bring your testing environment onto your local PC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### My preferred solution

There are a couple of ways to do it but the best is to simply find and replace all uses of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` with a simple function call.

So your example would become:

```
include(get_my_path() . '/Includes/Connect.php');
```

Define your current run mode:

```
define('RUN_MODE_PRODUCTION', true); // in live mode
define('RUN_MODE_PRODUCTION', false); // debug mode
```

Now for the function definition:

```
function get_my_path() {
    if(RUN_MODE_PRODUCTION === true) {
        return '/my/path/';
    }
    return '/my/other/path';
}
```

Overriding the actual values in `$_SERVER` is bad idea. Should some one else later come to work on the project it will not be clear what is happening.

This is a very simplified version of the bootstrapping of environments that I use in production every day.

### Where you can't do it

- [Apache `SetEnv` family of functions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html#setenv)
- [mod_rewrite `RewriteRule ^$ /home \[E=VAR:VAL\]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

### Another way you can do it

When I setup my mass virtual environment for developing I encountered this issue. See http://blog.simonholywell.com/post/1516566788/team-development-server#virtual_document_root

Because I could not override `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` using either of the above methods I had to do it in an `auto_prepend_file`.

I would not recommend that you use this technique to solve this particular issue however as it is better solved at the application level in this case.

Comment: Except that you have a problem with the path to the file that includes `get_my_path()`

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` environment variable prior PHP. (Unless you fiddle with a CGI wrapper script).
Apache has a [`SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) directive, but that won't work for `DOCUMENT_ROOT` (special requirement of CGI env). Could give it an alternative name however `DOC_ROOT2` etc.

But you could globally override that variable within PHP, by using the php.ini `auto_prepend_file` setting, which can also be set using .htaccess again:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file ./override_docroot.php
```

And that script would then "globally" adapt your environment:

```
<?php
   $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = "...";
```

Answer (score 0):

That's configured through the web server, not through PHP.  For example, in Apache it's the `DocumentRoot` directive.

Why not use relative paths instead?  You can be completely independent of where the application is located if you use paths like `../Includes/Connect.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `DocumentRoot /your/desired/path/` in a VirtualHost section of Apache config for this site. The docs are [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot).