# set $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] default value

Tags: php

How can i set the value

`'localhost'`

to my

`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

in my project config.ini , i tried to do something like

```
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = 'localhost'
```

but this does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364069/can-i-change-value-of-serverdocument-root?rq=1

Comment: i need to do this in the config.INI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one of my sites I assign the root to a variable `$root` that is set in a configuration file included in each page.

```
if($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] == 'localhost') {
  $root = 'localhost';
}
else {
  $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}
```

then in my php scripts I can use `$root/path/to.file`

Comment: yes i know i tried this , but i was looking for the way to do this in the config.ini , but this will work  thank you!